# Click to call: Navigation is blocked

Tags: javascript, html, browser, tel

Im trying to implement a click to call link like this:

```
<a href="tel:+4912345678912">Tel: +4912345678912</a>
```

According to [developers.google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/click-to-call/) this should be working. It is not automatically clicked, only triggered when the user actually clicks on it. However the navigation is blocked in all major mobile browsers.

```
Navigation is blocked: tel:+4912345678912
```

It does work in Chrome Desktop and Samsung Mobile Browser. I also tried redirecting via

```
window.location.href = 'tel:+4912345678912';
```

but this leads to the same result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked it out myself. The problem was that the link was inside an iframe that was appended to the parent page. Changing the `<a>` tag to the following solved the issue:

```
<a target="_parent" href="tel:NUMBER">
```

If there are multiple nested iframes one might have to use `_top` instead of `_parent`.

Comment: In my case it was _blank